# Main menu not appearing on category pages

Tags: categories, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

Im creating a theme based on blankslate/Bootstrap and having an issue with the main nav appearing on category pages (seems to appear everywhere else ok.).

In header.php:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                      <?php
                      wp_nav_menu( array(
                      'menu'              => 'primary',
                      'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                      'depth'             => 2,
                      'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                      'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                      'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                      );
                      ?>
```

In Functions.php

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'themename' ),
) );
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: A few things: 1) **remove the `'menu'` parameter** from your `wp_nav_menu()` call. Only use `'theme_location'`. 2) What is your "category page"? The *category archive index* (`category.php`) or a custom page template? Or something else? 3) Can we see a live link that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You need to show your walker code.

Comment: Check CSS to see if there are some required elements to display menu. The "collapse" in menu ID is suspect.

Comment: Ive taken the site out of maintenance mode, http://www.reallybadmovies.co.uk/  so, if you click on any of the menu items bar the sample page (just to demo works ok on others). the main nav not appearing.

I think the CSS is ok, as a look at the HTML shows me that the menu items arent actually being generated.

My category page is category.php, and isnt a custom one

Regarding the walker nav, its just using the settings as per https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

I removed the main menu reference as suggested, and problem still persists unfortunately

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is quite old but since there is no answer yet an there are many similar questions on the WordPress support forums, I'll better share my findings and maybe help someone.

The issue of disappearing menu may be caused by code in plugin or theme incorrectly modifying global `$wp_query` object using `pre_get_posts` filter hook.

I discovered that the code causing issues was in theme:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
                'post',
                'projects',
            ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

This snippet is supposed to add custom post types to category archives but it also affected query in `wp_nav_menu`.

To fix the issue, I had to correct the `if` condition:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_archive() && (is_category() || is_tag()) && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {

    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
                'post',
                'projects',
            ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

YMMV and the cause could be entirely different, but this is how I fixed the issue of missing menu in category template.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
    if ($q->get('post_type') != 'post') {
        return;
    }
```

in the handler of pre_get_posts fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was adding the filter `pre_get_posts` and missing to pass the menu item to the post. This is how I solved:

Before, I had this code in my theme's `functions.php` wich I was overwriting the main query with the `$post_type` only, whitout passing the menu items, and the menu was not appearing:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type' );
function query_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        } else {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', 'post', 'departments' );
        }
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type );

        return $query;
    }
}
```

And I solved passing the `'nav_menu_item'` as follow:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type' );
function query_post_type( $query ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', $post_type );
        } else {
            $post_type = array( 'nav_menu_item', 'post', 'departments' );
        }
        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_type );

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found out that the error is caused by this code snippet

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() ) {

    if( is_post_type_archive( 'project' ) && 'project' === $query->query['post_type'] ){
        $cur_date = date('Ymd', time());

        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu' );
    }
    if(is_category()){
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'collections', 'tribe_events'));
    }
}}, 10, 2 );
```

The changes made include adding the condition **$query->is_main_query()** to ensure it's the main query on the page and checking **empty($query->query['post_type'])** before setting the **post_type** to avoid overwriting existing settings if they are already specified in the query. These adjustments should help prevent conflicts and ensure proper navigation on category pages.

Here is the full working code that helped me:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {

    if (is_post_type_archive('project') && 'project' === $query->query['post_type']) {
        $cur_date = date('Ymd', time());

        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        $query->set('orderby', 'menu');
    }

    if (is_category() && empty($query->query['post_type'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'collections', 'tribe_events'));
    }
}}, 10, 1);
```