# Main menu not appearing in custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

My site's main menu shows everywhere except on the archive of a custom post type "object".

This is caused by this `pre_get_posts` callback. If I remove it, the menu shows up:

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'frontend_pre_get_posts_handler'), 99);

// .... 


public function frontend_pre_get_posts_handler($query){

      if (is_admin()) {
        return;
      }

      // Tweak which posts to display on frontpage, and order them by "unsold first".
      if ((is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query()) || is_post_type_archive('objet')) {
        $query->set('post_type', array(
          'objet', 'nav_menu_item'
        ));
        $query->set('meta_key', 'wpcf-objet-disponibilite');
        $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC'));
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 30);
      }
}
```

I have added the `nav_menu_item`post type, as I suggested in [other similar issues](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142439/main-menu-not-appearing-on-category-pages), and also changed the priority to 99 to make sure this runs at the end of the hook.

Still, no dice. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you use the `is_post_type_archive( 'object' )` condition you're checking whether the *main* query is a post type archive, not whether *this* query is a post type archive. This means that your code will apply to all queries, including for menus, on the post type archive.

You need to use `$query->is_post_type_archive()` to check the specific query that is currently being filtered. You already did this correctly for `$query->is_main_query()`.

```
if ((is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query()) || $query->is_post_type_archive('objet')) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Indeed! I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you for opening up my eyes!

Comment: Note: this works too  `if ((is_front_page()|| is_post_type_archive('objet'))  && $query->is_main_query()) { `

Comment: That's because `$query->is_main_query()` is now being checked even if you're not checking the front page, so it's the equivalent of saying "if it's any query on the post type archive AND it's the main query." It's simpler to just check if it's the post type archive query.